# Then .then() function seems to run before the promise is finished

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform

In the following code, the controller runs a function in a service that logs "object was destroyed". That function returns a promise.

On the .then() of that promise, in the controller, it logs "deleted"

"object was destroyed" should be logged first, and then (in the.then()) it should log "deleted". Unfortunately, it seems as if "deleted" is logged first.

**It seems as if the .then() of the promise is ran before the function completes.**

app.js

```
this.deleteData = function (db, objectId) {                                      
         var database = Parse.Object.extend(db);                                      
         var query = new Parse.Query(database);                                       
         return query.get(objectId, {                                                 
             success: function (result) {                                             
                 result.destroy({                                                     
                     success: function (result) {                                     
                         console.log("object was destroyed");                         
                     },                                                               
                     error: function (result, err) {                                  
                         console.log("object was not destroyed");                     
                         console.log(err);                                            
                     }                                                                
                 });                                                                  
             },                                                                       
             error: function (result, err) {                                          
                 console.log(err);                                                    
             }                                                                        
         });                                                                          
     }
```

Controller

```
function ResourcesCtrl ($scope, globalFunctions, CRUD) {   
    $scope.deleteResource = function (objectId) {                                    
        CRUD.deleteData('resources', objectId).then(function (result2) {             
             console.log("deleted");                                                  
             refreshResources();                                                                                                                   
         });                                                                          
     }
```

Comment: What is `Parse.Query` is it `$resource` or `http` call? `$resource` does not return a promise.

Comment: I think Parse.Query itself is an object, but it has functions (like get()) that are promises. here are the docs: http://sdsd(https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html

Answer (score 0):

The call to result.destroy() inside the success call back is asynchronous so therefore your success function will continue on and return and then promise that you return from your deleteData function will be resolved. All this before callback for result.destroy().

Ultimately you want deleteData to return the promise from result.destroy().

Here is a rough example

```
this.deleteData = function (db, objectId) {                                      
    var database = Parse.Object.extend(db);                                      
    var query = new Parse.Query(database);                                       
    return query.get(objectId).then(function (result) {                                             
            return result.destroy().then(function (result) {                                     
                    console.log("object was destroyed");                         
                }, function (err) {                                  
                    console.log("object was not destroyed");                     
                    console.log(err);                                            
                });                                                                
            }, function (err) {                                          
                console.log(err);                                                    
            });                                                                                                                                                
};
```

and then if you don't need the logging in can be even more succinct

```
this.deleteData = function (db, objectId) {                                      
    var database = Parse.Object.extend(db);                                      
    var query = new Parse.Query(database);                                       
    return query.get(objectId).then(function (result) {                                             
        return result.destroy();                                                                
    });                                                                                                                                             
};
```